# POST video to Facebook Page through Graph API using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to post videos on my facebook page using API in php but I'm getting following error:

```
No permission to publish the video
```

Following is my code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '184937xxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => '63ba95384b898fxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);

$data = [
  'title' => 'My Foo Video',
  'description' => 'This video is full of foo and bar action.',
  'source' => $fb->videoToUpload('test.mp4'),
];
$pageAccessToken ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
try {
  //825870214256735 is page id
  $response = $fb->post('/825870214256735/videos', $data, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: And what permissions did you grant to the app …?

Comment: These are the permissions: http://prntscr.com/g1e7i7

Clips Bank is App I'm using for my page.

Comment: You need `publish_pages` permission to publish in the name of a page.

Comment: It worked, but it posted from my account to page. I need to publish post with page it self so that i can be seen by all users who liked it.

Comment: If it published in the name of your user account, then you did not really use a page access token.

Comment: You mean I'm using wrong access token?

Comment: @CBroe yes you were right, I tried an other token and it worked. Thanks sir.